# List of Items in XML, howto add the correct attributes

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

My XML data structure looks like this..

```xml
  <SalesOrders>
    <SalesOrder>
      <Id>123</Id>
      ....
    </SalesOrder>
  </SalesOrders>
```

My C# code look like this.

```cs
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SalesOrders", Namespace = "")]
 public class SalesOrders : List<SalesOrder> { }
 public class SalesOrder {
    public int Id{get;set;}
 }
```

Deserializing this works fine, but I'm constrained  to that the name of the class "SalesOrder" must match the name of the Tag < SalesOrder >. I'm not able to figure out howto decorate my list or my item in such a way that it is possible to have "name mismatch" on them.. Anyone..

Comment: You probably [don´t want to derive from `List<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt), but just have a class that has a list and an `Id`-property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you usually [won´t need to - and shouldn´t - inherit `List<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt). Instead your class can **have** a list.

Furthermor you can use the `Name`-property of the `Xml...Attribute` in order to provide the different name in the xml than in your class-hierarch.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SalesOrders", Namespace = "")]
public class MyArbitraryName
{
    [XmlElement("SalesOrder")]
    public List<SalesOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class SalesOrder 
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
}
```